# Angularjs state url rely on numeric url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following url in my state:

```
    .state('forum.spesific', {
      url: '/:articleId',
      templateUrl: 'modules/forum/client/views/forum.client.view.html',
      controller: 'forumController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
.state('forum.spesific2', {
      url: '/:articleId',
      templateUrl: 'modules/forum/client/views/forum2.client.view.html',
      controller: 'forumController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
```

how can i make one of them rely on that the :articleId is only number, and the other mix of numbers and characters?

like:

```
  .state('forum.spesific', {
          url: '/:articleId ONLY BY NUMBER',
          templateUrl: 'modules/forum/client/views/forum.client.view.html',
          controller: 'forumController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
        })
    .state('forum.spesific', {
          url: '/:articleId BOTH ( have to be both)',
          templateUrl: 'modules/forum/client/views/forum2.client.view.html',
          controller: 'forumController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `regex-like` syntax: `'/articles/{id:int}'`, that matches only integers.
By the way, this is not very-safe because id (eg: `bigInt`) can be out of the javascript safe integer range... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

Comment: so in this case it would be /:articleid:int , then articleid would be within int?

what about the other? would that work with a string?

Comment: you just need to put the `{mixed}` param route after the `{int}` param route.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify regex like so:

```
 .state('forum.spesific', {
      url: '/{articleId:[0-9]+}',
      templateUrl: 'modules/forum/client/views/forum.client.view.html',
      controller: 'forumController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
.state('forum.spesific2', {
      url: '/{articleId:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}',
      templateUrl: 'modules/forum/client/views/forum2.client.view.html',
      controller: 'forumController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
```

but why 2 states if the only difference is the id type ?

Comment: @DMISSOKHO , thats because im relying on if the id is a number or a mixed one. mixed one will show a topic, when number will show page number .

but wouldnt spesific2 match the forum.spesific too, the 2nd state would be true on both?

Comment: if you want to have 2 behaviour with the ID you can test the type in your controller . For the second one you can use an other regex. I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can merge those 2 states into the same and change the `templateUrl`

`templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                if(isNaN(stateParams.articleId)){
                  return "modules/forum/client/views/forum2.client.view.html"
                } else {
                  return "modules/forum/client/views/forum.client.view.html";
                }
            }`

Hope this helps